# Passing array variable into Set-ItemProperty

Tags: powershell-3.0

I'm having a problem where, instead of passing an array item into the Set-ItemProperty command, its sending the entire array contents. Thanks in advance for taking a look at this, I really appreciate any help I can get.

```
$IPArray = @(Get-Content "C:\IPs.txt")

Set-ItemProperty IIS:\Sites\MYSite -name bindings -value @{protocol="http"; bindinginformation="$IPArray[0]:80:"}
```

I would expect it to pass in the first item in the array to that particular website, but instead it passes thru everything in the array. So, if my array has 5 items, there are 5 IP addresses bound to that website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
Set-ItemProperty IIS:\Sites\MYSite -name bindings -value @{protocol="http"; bindinginformation="$($IPArray[0]):80:"}
```

Comment: Thanks C.B.! That did the trick. If you don't mind, what's the difference between the two?

Comment: Glad to help. To expand in a string a variable with his property or index for array variable you need to enclose it in @() notation.